# Setting up Gmail Mail service in JBoss AS 7

Tags: email, gmail, jboss7.x, mail-server

Hi I am trying to setup a Mail service that uses gmail server. When I try to run the tests though, I get the following exception.

```
 09:48:35,334 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-31702353)) 
 javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, 
 port: 465;
 09:48:35,335 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-31702353))
 nested exception is:
 09:48:35,335 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-31702353))    
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
 PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.
 SunCertPathBuilderException:unable to find valid certification path 
 to requested target
```

This is my Configuration in standalone-full.xml

```
        <mail-session jndi-name="java:/Mail">
            <smtp-server ssl="true" outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp">
                <login name="mygmailaccount@gmail.com" password="mypassword"/>
            </smtp-server>
        </mail-session>

       <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
         <remote-destination host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465"/>
       </outbound-socket-binding>
```

**Am I missing something ?**

Answer (score 0):

Two differences compared to how I use it (which works fine for me, of course)

1) I'm using smtp.googlemail.com instead, so try

```
<remote-destination host="smtp.googlemail.com" port="465"/>
```

2) Also, might not be important but I also set the from-attribute, like this

```
<mail-session jndi-name="java:/Mail" from="mygmailaccount@gmail.com">
```

br,
Jens

Answer (score 0):

Given exception you get is during SSL handshake I would say that you must be using extra old JDK or there is something wrong with truststore you have configured.

Try with newer jdk & without any custom truststore configuration, or modify your truststore to also include CA certificates that are used by google.

Your configuration looks fine and works for me.